# Cannot output file info with get-childitem when using variable for computer name

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to read a list of computers from a .txt file, then look for a specific file named engage.* that exists in a specific directory on the pcs, then output the file info for engage.* to a csv file.   However, when using the $computer variable in the get-childitem command, no data is outputted.   Here is my script:

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path \scripts\pclist.txt  

foreach ($computer in $computers){

Get-ChildItem  -path "\\$computer\C$\Pfx Engagement\WM\Workpapers\*\engage.*" |
export-csv "c:\scripts\engage3.csv" -notypeinformation -encoding utf8
}
```

If I test by running the script for a specific pc name, it works great and outputs the file info to the .csv file:

```
Get-ChildItem  -path "\\0543834Laptop\C$\Pfx Engagement\WM\Workpapers\*\engage.*" |
export-csv "c:\scripts\engage2.csv" -notypeinformation -encoding utf8
```

The get-childitem cmd does not like using the $computer variable in the foreach loop.  I cannot find anything after hrs of research that says you cannot use a variable in the get-childitem cmd.   Is there something obvious I'm overlooking here?   thanks for any suggestions.

hrs of googling and editing my code.

Comment: A UNC path starts with two backslashes: `"\\$computer\C$...`.  If you `echo $computer`, does it show you the names?

Comment: You're definitely overlooking showing us how the `.txt` file looks.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @TimRoberts, the actual code _does_ contain ``\\``, but the lack of proper formatting of the post hides that fact.

Comment: The problem is _not_ one of string interpolation. Try `$computer = 'server1'; Write-Output "\\$computer\C$\Pfx Engagement\WM\Workpapers\*\engage.*"`, for instance. The implication of your symptom is that the value of `$computer` isn't the name of an existing server (that has the administrative `C$` share enabled).

Answer (score -1):

\ - escapes the character $, therefore, they use join-path

```
$disk = "c:\"
$folder = "temp"

$path = "$disk\$folder"  #dont work
$path = join-path $disk $folder #it works
```

You can use a workaround to avoid escaping:

```
$path = "\\" + $computer + "\C$\Pfx Engagement\WM\Workpapers*\engage.*"

Get-ChildItem -path $path | export-csv "c:\scripts\engage3.csv" -notypeinformation -encoding utf8 }
```

Comment: No, ``\`` has no special meaning in PowerShell (its escape character is `\``). Try `"\$HOME"` to see that `$HOME still expands.

Comment: this is true, although I remember for sure that it caused problems before

Comment: I'm not aware of any such issues. The  only issue with ``\`` - which is unrelated to string expansion (interpolation) - is that Windows PowerShell neglects to escape a trailing ``\`` when passing arguments with spaces to external programs (fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+).